# Why is the output of the third print 10 even if I have global b?

Tags: python

```
b=11
def outer():
    b=10
    print(b)
    def inner():
        global b
        print(b)
        b=20
    inner()
    print(b)
outer()
print(b)
```

The output of the third print is 10 instead of 20.But I have global b before print it.

Comment: I presume its because the `b` in `outer` isn't global

Comment: The scope of "global b" is only the inner function.

Comment: (btw a good example of why people tend to stay away from `global`, they are a pain in the neck and unless you are extremely careful they will create bugs...)

Comment: The `b` in `outer` is a local variable. The `b` in `inner` is a global variable, because `inner` has a `global b` statement.

Comment: Use a [nonlocal statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) instead of `global`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `global b`, it says: use b in/from the global scope.
You just need to understand what is the global scope. It is not the scope of the outer function nor the inner function, but the topmost scope of you python script.

When you `print(b)` in the outer function, you print the b defined in the outer's function scope, which is 10.

Outer and inner functions don't share the same scope.

Here a reference to Python's documentation, available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) under the `nested scope` definition.

> A function defined inside another function can refer to variables in
> the outer function. Note that nested scopes by default work only for
> reference and not for assignment. Local variables both read and write
> in the innermost scope. Likewise, global variables read and write to
> the global namespace. The nonlocal allows writing to outer scopes

You may want to read about the nonlocal here : [PEP 3104 -- Access to Names in Outer Scope](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).

You can use a simple trick to check what object is referenced in your code, with the `id(b)` function as:

```
print(id(b))
```

The following edited version of you test script will print more details on the variable you are printing:

```
b = 1100
print("line  2 = ", b, id(b), "before any function call")


def outer():
    b = 1000
    print("line  7 = ", b, id(b), "outer before inner() called")

    def inner():
        global b
        print("line 11 = ", b, id(b), "inner before")
        b = 2000
        print("line 13 = ", b, id(b), "inner after")
    inner()
    print("line 15 = ", b, id(b), "outer after inner() called")


outer()
print("line 19 = ", b, id(b), "global scope")
```

Output is:

```
line  2 =  1100 2438155730032 before any function call
line  7 =  1000 2438155720816 outer before inner() called
line 11 =  1100 2438155730032 inner before
line 13 =  2000 2438155730000 inner after
line 15 =  1000 2438155720816 outer after inner() called
line 19 =  2000 2438155730000 global scope
```

This way, you can see what object is printed, and understand when an existing object is used or a new one is created.

Don't forget that assigning to an immutable type(object) will not change (mute) the object, but create a new one. This means that in line 12, the assignment `b = 2000` will create a new object referenced by b in the global scope, replacing the previous b referencing the object created in the first line of the script.

Now, as a conclusion, no need to "stay away" from global or nonlocal. Use them when you need to, but **only** if you understand them.